# Linear algebra puzzle

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I stumbled upon an interesting problem in my calculations, which I can't figure out how to solve directly. It goes as follows: show that

$$
-2\left(I\otimes (Z-Q)C^{-1} + (Z-Q)C^{-1} \otimes I \right)^{-1}vec(Q) = vec(C)
$$

where $C, Q$ are any square symmetric matrices and $Z$ is skew-symmetric; $I$ is identity matrix, and $vec(\cdot):\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is a vectorization opertor (vertical column stacking); $\otimes$ is a kronecker product.

One solution is to multiply both sides by $\left(I\otimes (Z-Q)C^{-1} + (Z-Q)C^{-1} \otimes I \right)$ and turning it to the Sylvester equation of the form $-2Q=(Z-Q)C^{-1}C + C\left((Z-Q)C^{-1}\right)^T \implies -2Q=-2Q$.

**Q:** how to do this directly, without getting rid of vectorization, just by shuffling around the LHS of the first equation?

Comment: What does $vec(C)$ mean for a square symmetric matrix $C$?

Comment: Oh, that's a vectorization operator, look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics). Basically, just columns of a matrix stacked vertically in a vector

Comment: OK, thanks for the quick response.